# Adding material to inside of cube

Tags: modeling, materials, normals, boolean-modifier

I have a plane to which I added a solidify modifier which I have applied. I have then created a boolean shape which again I have now applied. Now when I apply a texture to the model I am seeing the reverse of the texture through the hole left by the boolean. How would I colour the reverse of the face?[image]